# Get IP address with URL string? (Java)

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, inetaddress

In my program a user enters a url string, say

http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~hawkeng//fall01/graphics/potato.gif

how would I get the IP address of this url?  I tried using

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(urlStr);
```

but the result always comes back null.  What is the proper way to get the IP address?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(urlString).getHost());
```

To get the raw IP:

```
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, though it returns a name/ip address.  If I want to use the IP address for a socket do I need to use the '/' as a delimiter to only extract the ip address or would it work as is?

Comment: just call address.getHostAddress() on the InetAddess object to get a string version of the IP.  Or better, create the socket directly with the InetAddress object.

Comment: @brettw: I edited my answer at the same time that you commented.

Answer (score 10):

You need to give `hostname` to [getByName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) method and it returns

> the IP address of a host, given the host's name.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~hawkeng//fall01/graphics/potato.gif");
System.out.println(url.getHost());
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
System.out.println(address.toString());
```

Output = `www.engineering.uiowa.edu/128.255.17.182`

To get the `IP address`

```
String temp = address.toString();
String IP = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("/")+1,temp.length());
```