# How to spot current ISP with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, ip

I need to spot current Internet Service Provider name. Is there any way to do something like:

(PSEUDOCODE):

```
String currentISP = driver.getCurrentISP();
if (currentISP == "Washington State University") {
// etc
}

else {
//
}
```

Comment: Just a note: you've got an assignment `=` in your `if`, while you probably want an `==` or `===`

Answer (score 1):

Use `driver.getCurrentURL()` to get the url.

Convert that to the IP using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286861/get-ip-address-with-url-string-java) solution

Finally, go from IP to ISP using some other webservice. SO has multiple questions with distinct answers, so I won't post one here.