# Get ip from udp url/address in tracker

Tags: java, bittorrent

In Java, or more generally, if I have a tracker announce url like: `udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969`, how can I acquire the ip address to add to the constructor of a `DataGramPacket` that requires an `InetAddress`?

Or am I missing something and this information is available somewhere else in a `.torrent` file?

In the BitTorrent specification I can only find how it is done with `http` addresses but all torrents I find use `udp` for their trackers.

Answer (score 0):

It's close to impossible to run a popular public **http** tracker today. as they take too much resources to run. When a tracker gets to popular, it has to use only **UDP**.

BitTorrent **UDP** trackers are specified in [BEP15 - UDP Tracker Protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101194115/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html).

To get the IP-address for the URL, use DNS.

Answer from [Get IP address with URL string? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286861/get-ip-address-with-url-string-java/9286956#9286956) by [Victor Stafusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540552/victor-stafusa):

> Try this:
>
> `InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(urlString).getHost());`
>
> To get the raw IP:
>
> `String ip = address.getHostAddress();`

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind it but I don't know where to send the packet to.

Comment: Ok, I thought DNS was only used for http. Do you know of any Java library for this or another resouce to check out? Have tried googling it quite a bit but found nothing useful.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how DNS works. Thought it needed the protocol to look things up but it only uses the domain name. That makes a lot of sense. It is possible to simply use the getByName method on the domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Note that you should use `getAllByName` instead, since a tracker may have ipv4 and ipv6 addresses and you need to announce to one per address family